# Illustrator CC, проверить цвета в swatches на соответствие критериям

Tags: javascript, adobe, illustrator

Пишу скрипт для поиска объектов, содержащих 4 краски в черном цвете. Рабочий скрипт здесь, и с ним всё хорошо:

https://github.com/glugoff/AI-scripts/blob/main/script-color-check-v2.3

Однако, помимо patchItems и textFrames, искомые цвета могут содержать объекты swatch, которые имеют тип CMYKcolor. Я не могу разобраться, как обратиться к их цветам, и проверить на соответствие критериям/исключениям, как это сделано в вышеуказанном скрипте. Работать с ними как с patchItems не получается. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Спасибо!